# Why do std::set and set::map's default constructors require heap allocation?

Tags: c++, memory-management, stdmap, stdset

When I try this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <set>

template<class T>
struct MyAlloc
{
    typedef std::allocator<T> Base;
    typedef typename Base::value_type value_type;
    typedef typename Base::pointer pointer;
    typedef typename Base::const_pointer const_pointer;
    typedef typename Base::reference reference;
    typedef typename Base::const_reference const_reference;
    typedef typename Base::size_type size_type;
    typedef typename Base::difference_type difference_type;
    Base a;
    MyAlloc() { }
    template<class U> MyAlloc(MyAlloc<U> const &) { }
    template<class U> struct rebind { typedef MyAlloc<U> other; };
    pointer allocate(size_type n, void const * = NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Allocating " << n << " objects" << std::endl;
        return this->a.allocate(n);
    }
    void deallocate(pointer p, size_type n) { return this->a.deallocate(p, n); }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::set<int, std::less<int>, MyAlloc<int> > set;
}
```

I see `Allocating 1 objects`.

But I don't understand -- why is this heap allocation necessary? Stack memory is sufficient for default-constructing other containers (like `std::vector`), so why do `set` and `map` require heap allocation?

Comment: Are you using MS VC++?

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: Yes.

Comment: Good question. I don't think it's "necessary". I see no dynamic allocations when I run this on my machine (OS X with clang).

Comment: @H2CO3: Interesting... if it wasn't necessary I feel like it'd be such an obvious optimization that Dinkumware would put it in. Makes me wonder why it's not there, I feel like it might break some code but I'm not sure what it would be.

Comment: I recall there once was a trick of a `static` global node that somehow marked empty or end instead of `nullptr` so implementations could aboid extra branches in some cases: if so, maybe this is the fix to that (it had issues) with a per-`map` node instead of a global one... Not sure why it would need to be on the heap however?

Comment: @Yakk: Actually I think I figured it out! Will post soon...

Comment: IIRC, MS VC++/Dinkumware empty collections still allocated memory. Not sure if this is still true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>I think I figured it out myself. Visual C++ seems to be correct, and Clang and GCC seem to be wrong.</strike>

It's because `swap` should not invalidate iterators for `std::set` or `std::map`. If we try this code:

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::set<int> a, b;
    std::set<int>::iterator end = a.end();
    a.swap(b);
    b.insert(end, 1);
    std::cout << b.size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If the head of the tree was stored on the stack, then `end` would become invalidated after the swap.

Visual C++ handles it just fine, but GCC and Clang loop infinitely (at least on my versions).

**Edit**: The above may have been the reason until C++03 due to an ambiguity, but it is no longer the case since C++11 -- please see the comments below.

Comment: Could you cite the corresponding paragraph of the standard mandating that swap should not invalidate iterators for std::set or std::map, please? Will you submit a bug report or shall I do it?

Comment: Nitpick: Clang and GCC are not C++ library implementations, they can both use libstdc++ and Clang prefers its own libc++. MSVC, in contrast, can use only its own torn apart Dinkumware implementation. I say torn apart because there are a ton of compiler bug workaround present in MSVC's library code. Also, you are wrong (see note 2 [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6442829/256138)).

Comment: See the answer above the one I linked to, note 1, for c++03. Also, typing these things on a phone, while possible, is hard and time-consuming ;-)

Comment: @rubenvb: Nice to see that question referenced :)

Comment: @rubenvb: Wow, thanks for the pointer. I guess the explanation is probably that they were trying to avoid breaking programs that relied on `end` iterators staying valid. Thanks!

Comment: @Mehrdad that sounds like something Microsoft would do, yes `;-)`.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard certainly doesn't mandate that memory is allocated for a default constructed object. Why an implementation might choose to allocate in the default constructor of a `std::map<...>` I don't know. One reason could be to make sure that it doesn't try to embed a potentially large allocator into the stack allocated object. You'd need to look at the implementation to see why it allocates memory on the heap.